# Computer hung, when restarted, stated in BIOS that the CPU clock was decreased from usual clock/speed

Tags: boot, cpu, bios, freeze, clockspeed

At random times, while in idle time or gaming, the computer hangs, no mouse cursor movement, no BSOD.

I then use the restart button on the computer.

When restarted and entering the boot screen, the CPU clock is stated lower than it should (2,66 GHz), about 1,4 GHz. And the BIOS says that the setting in the BIOS was wrong.

So, I enter the BIOS and do "Load setup defaults", then I change again to my previous settings, which was the boot logo and the boot sequence only.
After that, it runs normally again.

The hang of the computer happens 1x-3x at a time, with the "Load setup defaults" done only once.

My computer specs:

- CPU Intel [Core2Duo E6750](http://ark.intel.com/products/30784/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E6750-4M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB?q=E6750) (2,66 GHz )
- Motherboard Asus P5K
- Memory 4x Team 1GB pc 6400
- GPU Nvidia 9800 GT ( Pixelview brand )
- HDD WDC 1TB SATA
- Power Supply FSP 400W
- Asus DVD-RW SATA

The computer is about 6 years old, running Windows XP SP-3, and it's not overclocked.

What could be the problem with this computer?

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, you need a new bios/cmos battery - since its dead, your system is not saving bios settings and going back to its safe defaults. In my experience, they usually last around 5 years, so if you're using the original one, you can simply swap it out for a new one. Most of the time they're CR2032 button cells mounted on the motherboard. You can use a very small screwdriver to push down on retaining hook at the bottom and the old battery will pop right out. You can then simply replace it with a new one.

[image]

Comment: thanks for replying. unfortunately, i have already replace the cmos battery within a year ago ( November 2012 ) because the time keep changing..